# how can I use Unix Domain Socket in Android both server and client,with gRPC

Tags: java, android, flutter, grpc, grpc-java

I want to use Unix Domain Socket in android-java with grpc server.And I use the example from okhttp:https://github.com/square/okhttp/blob/master/samples/unixdomainsockets/src/main/java/okhttp3/unixdomainsockets/UnixDomainServerSocketFactory.java

I have tried this:

```
InetSocketAddress address = new InetSocketAddress("localhost", port); 
Server server = OkHttpServerBuilder.forPort(address,InsecureServerCredentials.create())
.socketFactory(new UnixDomainServerSocketFactory(socketFile)) 
.build().start();
```

But I got an error :

```
java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError: Cannot determine cpu address size E/AndroidRuntime(19579):   
at jnr.ffi.Platform.calculateAddressSize(Platform.java:314) E/AndroidRuntime(19579):    
at jnr.ffi.Platform.<init>(Platform.java:290) E/AndroidRuntime(19579):  
at jnr.ffi.Platform.<init>(Platform.java:31) E/AndroidRuntime(19579):   
at jnr.ffi.Platform$Supported.<init>(Platform.java:582) E/AndroidRuntime(19579): 
at jnr.ffi.Platform$Linux.<init>(Platform.java:730) E/AndroidRuntime(19579):    
at jnr.ffi.Platform.determinePlatform(Platform.java:193) E/AndroidRuntime(19579):   
at jnr.ffi.Platform.determinePlatform(Platform.java:211) E/AndroidRuntime(19579):   
at jnr.ffi.Platform.access$000(Platform.java:31) E/AndroidRuntime(19579):   
at jnr.ffi.Platform$SingletonHolder.<clinit>(Platform.java:40) E/AndroidRuntime(19579):     
at jnr.ffi.Platform.getNativePlatform(Platform.java:327) E/AndroidRuntime(19579):   
at jnr.unixsocket.SockAddrUnix.<clinit>(SockAddrUnix.java:34) E/AndroidRuntime(19579):  
at jnr.unixsocket.SockAddrUnix.create(SockAddrUnix.java:174) E/AndroidRuntime(19579):   
at jnr.unixsocket.UnixSocketAddress.<init>(UnixSocketAddress.java:47) E/AndroidRuntime(19579):  
at com.example.grpc_proxy.unixdomainsockets.UnixDomainServerSocketFactory$UnixDomainServerSocket.bind(UnixDomainServerSocketFactory.java:54) E/AndroidRuntime(19579):   
at java.net.ServerSocket.bind(ServerSocket.java:331) E/AndroidRuntime(19579):   
at io.grpc.okhttp.OkHttpServer.start(OkHttpServer.java:79) E/AndroidRuntime(19579):     
at io.grpc.internal.ServerImpl.start(ServerImpl.java:185) E/AndroidRuntime(19579):  
at io.grpc.internal.ServerImpl.start(ServerImpl.java:94)
```

So how can I use Unix domain socket for android as a server with gRPC.LocalServerSocket isn't a serverSocket,so it can't be returned.

Comment: Cross-posting: https://github.com/grpc/grpc-java/issues/10352